# How can I filter sales_order_shipment.list by order increment_id

Tags: api, magento, xml-rpc

I want to find the shipments on an order (sales order info does not appear to have this information) [Data::Printer Dump Format](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter)

```
[0] "sales_order_shipment.list",
[1] [
    [0] {
        increment_id   {
            eq   100000025
        }
    }
]
```

but this filters by shipment increment id. Also this

```
[0] "sales_order_shipment.list",
[1] [
    [0] {
        order_increment_id   {
            eq   100000025
        }
    }
]
```

which throws a SQL error. I suspect I need to join the tables via the API somehow, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using SOAP API calls? Which Magento Version? And please post your API calls.

Comment: provide some code details so that we can sort out .

Comment: I'm using XML-RPC, not sure what you need more code wise, I'm just trying to figure out how to get the shipment by order increment id.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using a filter on the order's `order_id` value.

Note that `order_id` is different to the order's `increment_id` which is the usual customer facing reference number. Therefore an extra step is required to convert the order's reference into the `order_id`.

I can describe the method:

1. Get the order data for your order number (`increment_id`) using `sales_order.info` API call
2. get the `order_id` from the order data
3. Use the `order_id` as a filter in `sales_order_shipment.list`
4. This will give you a list of shipments each with an `increment_id`. This id is the shipment's reference.
5. Use the shipment's `increment_id` in `sales_order_shipment.info` to get more details.